# I created a category name and i want to use that category's slug for some pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a category that name is "about-us" and slug name is "about" for this category name.
and I have some pages name is Company,Team,contact-us.

So now i want to create permalinks following.
https://www.example.com/about/company
https://www.example.com/about/Team

Still I am facing problem and what should I have to do.
*I am able to select template for particular page also able to pic created category but  in permalinks that is not working.
* I don't want to select any parent page for particular page so help me out.
* If any snippet is available  and anyone know about that then help me out .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try by sub page. First create a "About Us" page. Then you can create page Company,Team,contact-us. All pages should have the parent page About us.

For example you want the permalink like https://www.example.com/about/company

Here "about" parent page slug and the "company" is the subpage name.

Comment: I don't  want to create parent page "about" .

Comment: I want to create category  and category slug want to use  with pages